# How to generate random alphanumeric string in julia?

Tags: random, julia

I am trying to generate 12 characters alphanumeric string in julia with the following snippets:
a) 
`an = randstring(rand(Bool) ? ('A':'Z') : ('0':'9'), 12)`

b)

```
an = "" 
for i in [1:12]
    an *= randstring(rand(Bool) ? ('A':'Z') : ('0':'9'))
end
```

but both gives either complete 12 digits or 12 alphabets but not of their combination.

please guide me in generating combination of 12 alphanumeric string.

Comment: Be aware that `for i in [1:12]`means something completely different from `for i in 1:12`. Are you sure this was your intention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't mind using both upper and lower case letters, you can simply call `randstring(12)`:

```
julia> using Random

julia> randstring(12)
"0IPrGg0JVONT"

julia> randstring(12)
"EB5dhw4LVno7"
```

If you want only uppercase letters (and numbers), then you need to pass `randstring` a collection that includes only uppercase letters and numbers, which you can achieve with `['A':'Z'; '0':'9']`:

```
julia> randstring(['A':'Z'; '0':'9'], 12)
"ASZQAT5YX3OL"

julia> randstring(['A':'Z'; '0':'9'], 12)
"FEV5HTGMLQ6X"
```

Finally, note that you could provide the collection of characters as a string:

```
julia> randstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 12)
"ASZQAT5YX3OL"
```

Comment: Random.seed!(0) inside the function returns the same random alphanumeric string!

Comment: Yeah, don't put `Random.seed!(0)` inside your function. I just used that so you can exactly reproduce the results shown in my answer.

Comment: @AVA, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed for an explanation of random seeds, in case you're not already aware.

Comment: I removed `Random.seed!(0)` from the examples since random number generation is not guaranteed to be stable across Julia versions anyways.

Comment: `randstring('A':'Z', 2)` works as well. Note that `randstring(['A':'Z'], 2)` without `;` will give an error.