# How to generate random strings that matches a Regex in Julia?

Tags: regex, julia

Related questions:

- [Random string that matches a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp)
- [How to generate random alphanumeric string in julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453509/how-to-generate-random-alphanumeric-string-in-julia)

The question is fairly simple. I found numerous alternatives for other languages, but not in Julia:

[Random Text generator based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex/43377488#43377488)

Also `Random.randstring` doesn't take `Regex` as an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible to use [Automa.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/Automa.jl) to build a DFA and randomly traverse it.  Automa uses a simpler syntax than PCRE, so the languange you can describe by it should actually be regular.

I quickly threw together the following, based mostly on the code in [`dot.jl`](https://github.com/BioJulia/Automa.jl/blob/master/src/dot.jl):

```
julia> function rand_re(machine::Automa.Machine)
           out = IOBuffer()
           node = machine.start
           
           while true
               if node.state ∈ machine.final_states
                   (rand() ≤ 1 / (length(node.edges) + 1)) && break
               end
               
               edge, node = rand(node.edges)
               label = rand(collect(edge.labels))
               print(out, Char(label))
           end
           
           return String(take!(out))
       end
rand_re (generic function with 1 method)

julia> rand_re(Automa.compile(re"a[0-9][ab]+"))
"a6bbb"

julia> rand_re(Automa.compile(re"a[0-9][ab]+"))
"a9b"

julia> rand_re(Automa.compile(re"a[0-9][ab]+"))
"a3aa"

julia> rand_re(Automa.compile(re"a[0-9][ab]+"))
"a1a"

julia> rand_re(Automa.compile(re"a[0-9][ab]+"))
"a5ba"
```

The caveat is that Automa uses byte-encoded sets for edge labels, so more care should be taken where I just write `Char(label)`.

Since final states can still have outgoing edges, I chose to treat stopping and each edge with uniform probability.  I think this will likely have the effect that potentially infinite terms will either be very short or very long; google "Boltzmann samplers" for how to solve that (not to be confused with sampling from a Boltzmann distribution!), but the solution is rather mathematically involved.

Alternatively, you could use `ccall` or `PyCall` to call [`rxvm_gen`](https://github.com/eriknyquist/librxvm#id4) or [`Rxvm.gen`](https://github.com/eriknyquist/librxvm/blob/master/pyrxvm/README.rst#id12) of [`librxvm`](https://github.com/eriknyquist/librxvm), which contains (probably) a quite performant code for non-backtracking regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Julia has [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions),
which means its regular expressions are far more powerful than true regular expressions.
And are in-fact turing complete.
I suspect there is a bunch of interesting theoretical computer science around this.
I suspect your task for PCRE might be proved to be impossible because of [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
But still what we can do is try a bunch of random strings and toss out those that don't match.
And for simple regex that goes a long way.
Its not guaranteed  to give an answer though.

If one wanted stricter regex, like those covered by [Automa.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/Automa.jl),
there is probably something better that can be done, since you can walk the state machine
solving it 1 bit at a time.
Hopefully someone that knows Automa.jl can post their own answer.

#### Code

```
using Random: randstring

function rand_matching(regex; max_len=2^16, max_attempts=1000)
    for _ in max_attempts
        str  = randstring(max_len)
        m = match(regex, str)
        if m != nothing
            # rather than return whole string, 
            # just return the shortest bit that matches
            return m.match
        end
    end
    error("Could not find any string that matches regex")
end
```

#### demo:

```
julia> @time rand_matching(r"\d\d")
  0.013517 seconds (34.34 k allocations: 1.998 MiB)
"38"

julia> @time rand_matching(r"\d\d")
  0.001497 seconds (11 allocations: 128.656 KiB)
"44"

julia> @time rand_matching(r"a\d\d")
  0.000670 seconds (11 allocations: 128.656 KiB)
"a19"

julia> @time rand_matching(r"a\d\d")
  0.000775 seconds (11 allocations: 128.656 KiB)
"a83"

julia> @time rand_matching(r"a\d\db")
  0.000670 seconds (11 allocations: 128.656 KiB)
"a44b"
```

Comment: The multiple implementations found for other languages (even those implementing PCRE) make me believe that the task is not impossible, I didn't dive into the details, maybe they are using a stricter version of PCRE. Throwing random strings hoping that one match the regex is ok for small, simple regex but it doesn't scale very well... Thank you for pointing me towards Automa because it matches exactly the next step of my problem. And maybe it can kill two birds with one stone!

Comment: Further, even if it is not impossible (halting problem equiv),
it still should have huge time complexity. You can implement any problem as a PCRE regex that only accepts the solution.
So you can for example break public key encryption, wth a PCRE that only accept the private key, then ask for a random one.
Or implement any NP-Complete problem problem, like subset sum, that accept `T` or `F` depending on if the syubset sum exiists.
If your PCRE matching regex generator works in polynomial time, then congrats you've proved P=NP.

Comment: Hmm, maybe  PCRE  are not infact turing complete. I could just  be  plain wrong there. They may only be equivi to context free grammars.
They can do some mad things though, like prime detection.
So defs could be generating primes with your random string generator.
And can probably break public key cryptography.